Literature reference for variance of the variance of the binomial proportion
If K is the number of successes after $n$ Bernoulli trials with success probability $p$, it follows the binomial distribution: K $\sim$ Bin(n, p). The estimated proportion $\hat{p}= \frac{K}{n}$ is known to have variance $n^{-1}p(1-p)$.
Yet what is the variance of this variance estimator, i.e. $Var\left(n^{-1}\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})\right)$? I am trying to solve this using the higher moments of the binomial distribution, and will post the answer when I find it, but I was wondering if anyone has done the work for me. So any reference to extant literature or CV questions is very welcome.
Bradley et al. (2008) "Sampling Uncertainty and Confidence Intervals for the Brier Score and Brier Skill Score" provide a formula in their equation (29) but this feels wrong as it can easily yield negative variances. I cannot find the expression in Kenney and Keeping (1951) as referenced by them.
A delta method approximation is provided here, but I am looking for an exact solution.

Are you asking how to find the moments of a Binomial distribution?  Or how to compute the variance of $\hat p(1-\hat p),$ which evidently involves the first four moments of the estimator?

The second thing, so $Var(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))$

If the estimator is
$$\hat\theta = \frac{1}{n} \hat{p}(1-\hat{p}) =  -\frac{1}{n^3} k^2 + \frac{1}{n^2} k = ak^2+bk$$
Then it's variance can be related to the distribution of $k$ and it's moments
$$
Var[ak^2+bk] =E[a^2k^4 + 2abk^3+ b^2k^2] -E[ak^2+bk]^2 =a^2 E[k^4] + 2ab E[k^3] + b^2 E[k^2] - a^2 E[k^2]^2 -2ab E[k^2] E[k] - b^2 E[k]^2$$ fill in and simplify (I am too lazy to give the full answer).

I asked chatGPT to see how it does, and even they don't compute the entire answer and suggested to just fill in the expressions. I asked "Variance of aK+bK^2 when K is binomial distributed?", then "Could you finish step 3 by performing the substitution?", and "And what is that final expression?", and still nothing and it tells me "If you need a fully expanded and simplified expression, a symbolic algebra system would be useful to handle these higher-order polynomials.", so either you use something like Wolfram alpha, or you get pen and paper and work it out. It is annoying but not difficult.

Because the moment generating function of a single Bernoulli$(p)$ variable $X$ is, by definition,
$$\phi_p(t) = E\left[e^{tX}\right] = \Pr(X=0)e^{t0} + \Pr(X=1)e^{t1} = (1-p) + pe^t,$$
the mgf of $K,$ which is the sum of $n$ iid such variables, is
$$\phi_{n,p}(t) = \phi_p(t)^n = (1-p + pe^t)^n.$$
Expanding the right hand side in a MacLaurin series (Taylor series around $0$) through fourth order gives the moments $\mu_1,$ $\mu_2,$ $\mu_3,$ and $\mu_4$ of $K$ (which implicitly depend on $p$ and $n,$ of course),
$$\phi_{n,p}(t) = 1 + \frac{\mu_1}{1!}t + \frac{\mu_2}{2!}t^2 + \frac{\mu_3}{3!}t^3 + \frac{\mu_4}{4!}t^4  + \cdots$$
Consequently the moments of $\hat p = K/n$ are $\mu_1/n,$ $\mu_2/n^2,$ $\mu_3/n^3,$ and $\mu_4/n^4.$  Use these to compute
$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\hat p(1-\hat p)\right) &= \frac{1}{n^2}\left(E\left[(\hat p(1-\hat p))^2\right] - E[\hat p(1-\hat p)]^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\left(E[\hat p^2] - 2E[\hat p^3] + E[\hat p^4] - (E[\hat p] - E[\hat p^2])^2\right) \\
&= \frac{\mu_2}{n^4} - \frac{2\mu_3}{n^5} + \frac{\mu_4}{n^6} - \left(\frac{\mu_1^2}{n^4} - 2\frac{\mu_1\mu_2}{n^5} + \frac{\mu_2^2}{n^6}\right).
\end{aligned}$$
This works out to

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\hat p(1-\hat p)\right) = \frac{1}{n^5}\left((n-1)p(1-p) (n(1-2p)^2 + 6p(1-p) - 1) \right).$$

In case I mis-typed anything, here is executable R code for the same value that you can test:
V <- function(n, p) {
 ((n-1) * (1-p) * p * (n * (1 - 2*p)^2 + 6 * p * (1-p) - 1)) / n^5
}

Here's a one-second test:
set.seed(17)
n <- 5
p <- 1/3
c(Simulated = var(sapply(rbinom(5e5, n, p), \(k) k/n * (1 - k/n) / n)),
  Formula = V(n, p))


   Simulated      Formula 
0.0002531842 0.0002528395



I checked this numerically, and it seems correct, many thanks

Doesn't your expression give the variance of $\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})$ (as OP requested in the comments which seems to contradict the question itself)? When I plug in the moments of a Binomial into your expression, I get an expression with $n^5$ in the denominator (I might make a mistake, of course but my simulations seem to confirm this).

@COOLSerdash Thank you -- I had omitted the $1/n^2$ term that first showed up and my testing indeed had  compared variances of simulated values of $\hat p(1-\hat p)$ rather than $\hat p(1-\hat p)/n.$

@whuber Thanks for the derivation, but the problem is that it still requires true values. When I plug in $\hat{p}$ for p, the formula becomes biased. I can post this as a new question, as this is not clear from the original one

Your question said you were "looking for an exact solution" and this is it.  If you want an unbiased estimator you can seek one (in the usual way) as a polynomial in $\hat p$ (of degree 4), but beware that might not be what you really need: why unbiased and why unbiased in this (additive) sense?
